# how to parse date using SimpleDateFormat in java of type 2015-01-13T10:24:55Z

Tags: java, simpledateformat

i have the following date string coming from grails services in android app.

```
2015-01-13T10:24:55Z
```

Now i want to parse this string using `SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssz");`
but i am getting the error following error in logcat.

```
01-13 10:53:50.674: W/System.err(1794): java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2015-01-13T10:24:55Z" (at offset 10)
```

please let me know about how to parse this type of string.

Comment: "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ", perhaps? Or "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'". Keep the quotes consistent for the additional characters.

Comment: same exception occurs

Comment: I'm surprised by the exception occurring with an offset of 10 in either case. Please show a short but complete program demonstrating the problem.

Comment: I am getting the string from JSON String cdate=jsonobject.getString("open_Date"); SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssz"); Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); c.setTime(formatter.parse(cdate));

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Currently you're using the "general time zone" specifier. In order to have `Z` interpreted as "this value is in UTC", you should use `X`:

```
new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX", Locale.US)
```

`X` is an ISO-8601 time zone specifier, which includes `Z` for UTC.

Alternatively, you could quote it as a literal and explicitly specify the time zone as UTC:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'",
                                               Locale.US);
format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Etc/UTC"));
```

It's important to explicitly set the time zone in this case, as otherwise the value will be parsed using the system default time zone.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about specifying the explicitly timezone

Answer (score 1):

Surround `Z` in quotes 'Z' and also pass correct Locale information. Moreover to not rely on default timezone, set the timezone explicitly to `UTC`, so that your date can be parsed properly
E.g.

```
    public static void main(String args[]) throws ParseException {

    String date = "2015-01-13T10:24:55Z";
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'", Locale.CANADA);
    sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Etc/UTC"));
    Date parse = sdf.parse(date);
    System.out.println(parse);        
    }
```

Output

```
Tue Jan 13 10:24:55 CET 2015
```

Comment: Note that doing this *without* explicitly specifying the time zone of the `SimpleDateFormat` will leave it using the system default time zone, effectively misparsing the data.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks for the reply, I was in process of editing the answer when you posted comment

Comment: That doesn't do it - because you're still not setting the time zone, which is completely different to the locale.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks , I missed the `timezone` part completely.